# How to pass std::promise into a thread? by std::move or by std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

```
#include <future>

using namespace std;

void t1(promise<int> p)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
    p.set_value(0);
}

void t2(shared_ptr<promise<int>> p)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
    p->set_value(0);
}

future<int> f1()
{
    promise<int> p;
    async(t1, move(p));

    return p.get_future();
}

future<int> f2()
{   
    auto p = make_shared<promise<int>>();
    async(t2, p);

    return p->get_future();
}

int main()
{
    f1().get();
    f2().get();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is:

How to pass a `std::promise` object into a thread, **by `std::move` or by `std::shared_ptr`?**

**Which is better?**

Comment: Will you use the promise in the parent thread afterwards?

Comment: No. I won't use it after passing.

Comment: Then I see no need for a shared pointer, just move it.

Comment: why won't you just use `async` for it, as in: `auto future = async(launch::async, func);`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First get the future, then move the promise into the thread.

```
std::future<int> f() {
  std::promise<int> p;
  auto r=p.get_future();
  std::async(t1, move(p)); // THIS IS STUPID because it blocks until the thread finishes
  return r;
}
```

Of course this is stupid, because your use of `async` blocks until the task is complete.  But it is the proper use of `promise`.

Sharing a promise is bad, it should have unique ownership as only one should set its value.  And whomever that is should own its lifetime.

After moving from it, you can no longer get a future from it.

Comment: Is the future you get from a promise still valid after the source promise has moved?

Comment: @eric yes, it is.